# How to go to detail of the pokemon with poke api in react

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

I am listing pokemons with this api: https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/ so when I click the pokemon I want to go to the page.
So for this in details screen:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const pokemonId = props.match.params.id;
  const pokemonDetails = useSelector((state) => state.pokemonDetails);
  const { loading, error, pokemon } = pokemonDetails;

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(detailsPokemon(pokemonId));
  }, [dispatch, pokemonId]);
```

And my action:

```
export const detailsPokemon = (pokemonId) => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: POKEMON_DETAILS_REQUEST, payload: pokemonId });
  try {
    const { data } = await Axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemonId}`);
    dispatch({ type: POKEMON_DETAILS_SUCCESS, payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: POKEMON_DETAILS_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

And my reducer:

```
export const pokemonDetailsReducer = (
  state = { pokemon: {}, loading: true },
  action
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case POKEMON_DETAILS_REQUEST:
      return { loading: true };
    case POKEMON_DETAILS_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false, pokemon: action.payload };
    case POKEMON_DETAILS_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

But I am getting pokemon id undefined that's why I cannot go to the page.

```
export default function Pokemon(props) {
  const { pokemon } = props;
  return (
    <div key={pokemon.id} className="card">
      <a href={`/pokemon/${pokemon.id}`}>
        <img className="medium" src={pokemon.image} alt={pokemon.name} />
      </a>
      <div className="card-body">
        <a href={`/pokemon/${pokemon.id}`}>
          <h2>{pokemon.name}</h2>
        </a>
        <Rating
          rating={pokemon.rating}
          numReviews={pokemon.numReviews}
        ></Rating>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: How are you passing the pokemonId? are you using react router? please post how do you access to it.

Comment: As a props I am getting this: name: "jigglypuff"
url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/39/" So I need to pass 39 as an id

Comment: You're using the a tag when it seems like you are using react router, I would advise to use the Link component of react router if that's what you're using instead of the a tag.